# JavaFx2.x as webapplication

Tags: web-applications, javafx

Can any suggest me how to create a web application using javafx2.x, similar to web application that can be created using jsp,jsf.

Is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

Just read careflly user manual , I think that You are trying to make Java sevrlet without javascript. You might need to update Your JDK , as from 1.7uX JavaFx is part of JDK.

Comment: I am using update JDK, where JavaFX is part of my JDK.. I wish to have a demo of web application that has been created using javaFX2.x if it is possible.. i don't know how to create web applications , i have created desktop application in javafx 2.x.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong , is this that You try to implement:
http://manage.example.com/servlet/ViewAnnouncementServlet?canchange=false&announcementid=20638 ? I have stripped original URL , to avoid advertising.

Comment: I am not able to access the URL.

Comment: URL was just an example , and I am afraid to be flagged as spammer/advertiser if I post real URL. But , I'll risk to help You , just put xtraorbit instead of example. URL snip was to show You and ask You is this what You try to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you develop your webapplication with Netbeans, you can integrate javafx into a web application. You will require the jnlp to be embedded in the html or jsp.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://java.com/js/dtjava.js"></script>
    <script>
        function deployIt() {
            dtjava.embed(
                    {         id: "myApp",
                             url: "Fish.jnlp",
                           width: 300,
                          height: 200,
                     placeholder: "place"
                    },
                    { javafx: "2.1+" },
                    {}
            );
        }
        dtjava.addOnloadCallback(deployIt);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="place"></div>           
</body>
```

Reference : http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deployment_toolkit.htm

Comment: Thank you D3EP4K , but I am using eclipse Juno to develop the javafx application(since i am familiar with it). Kindly suggest if any possibilities are there..